# What libs in exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How do you figure out what libs were used to build an exe?
1. Using only exe
2. Having full dev env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. objdump, memory map (when exe's working) and [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/)
2. Looking at references and includes should help.

Answer (score 1):

For completenesses sake, on Linux you'd use ldd to see what dynamic library's was linked again... and 'objdump --syms' to get a listing of symbols...